# Turn Julia code in listings into pseudocode

Tags: listings, code, pseudocode

I am trying to automatically import code written in Julia and make it into semi-pseudocode. As an minimal example I am trying to replicate the following pseudocode style:

[image: Example Psudocode 1]

[image: Example Psudocode 2]

I am guessing this was made using the `algorithmx` package. My best attempt at replicating this style is shown in the following image

[image: My attempt so far]

However my code has some minor / major flaws:

- **How can I make everything that is not a keyword, nor a function name into maths?** It looks so much better than the `ttfamily` font.
- My topline defined in lset is not as thick as the one in the example. I know where it is defined, but not how to change it's width.
- It is not necessary to replicate the commenting style in the `AlgorithmX` examples.

***main.tex***

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 

% Defines fonts and language settnings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Tilpasning til norsk.
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{subcaption} \usepackage{caption}

% Defines the style for the codeblocks
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in }

\lstset{ frame=top,frame=bottom,
  basicstyle=\normalfont,
  stepnumber=1, % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1 each line will be numbered
  numbersep=10pt, % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  tabsize=2, % tab size in blank spaces
  extendedchars=true, %
  breaklines=true, % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=t, % sets the caption-position to top
  mathescape=true,
  mathescape=true,
  literate=
         {=}{$\leftarrow{}$}{1}
         {+=}{${}\uparrow{}$}{2}
         {==}{$={}$}{2}
         {||}{OR}{2},
  showspaces=false, % Leerzeichen anzeigen ?
  showtabs=false, % Tabs anzeigen ?
  xleftmargin=17pt, framexleftmargin=17pt, framexrightmargin=17pt,
  framexbottommargin=5pt,
  framextopmargin=5pt,
  showstringspaces=false % Leerzeichen in Strings anzeigen ?
} \lstMakeShortInline[columns=fixed]|

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+17pt\relax}{0.4pt}\par\vskip1pt#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt,
  font={sf},labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}

%%
%% Julia definition (c) 2014 Jubobs
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lstdefinelanguage{Julia}%
  {morekeywords={abstract,break,case,catch,const,continue,do,else,elseif,%
      end,export,false,for,function,immutable,import,importall,if,in,%
      macro,module,otherwise,quote,return,switch,true,try,type,typealias,%
      using,while},%
   sensitive=true,%
   alsoother={$},%
   morecomment=[l]\#,%
   morecomment=[n]{\#=}{=\#},%
   morestring=[s]{"}{"},%
   morestring=[m]{'}{'},%
}[keywords,comments,strings]%

\lstset{%
    language         = Julia,
    keywordstyle     = \bfseries,
    stringstyle      = \color{magenta},
    commentstyle     = \color{ForestGreen},
    showstringspaces = false,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=Julia, 
                 caption=Recursive route-counting function,
            ]{countRoutes1.jl}

\lstinputlisting[language=Julia, 
                 caption=Recursive route-counting function,
            ]{countRoutes2.jl}

\end{document}
```

***countRoutes1.jl***

```
function countRoutes(m, n)
    if n == 0 || m == 0
        return 1
    end
    return countRoutes(m, n - 1) + countRoutes(m - 1, n)
end
```

***CountRoutes2.jl***

Note some minor changes had to be made in order to make the pseudocode into runnable Julia code.

```
cache = Dict()

function countRoutes(m,n)
    if n == 0 || m == 0
        return 1
    end

    try
        return cache[(m, n)]
    end

    cache[(m, n)] = countRoutes(m, n - 1) + countRoutes(m - 1, n)
    return cache[(m, n)]
end
```